# .Net Core Web API User.Identity.Name is null

Tags: .net, .net-core, authorization, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently having an issue where I am trying to retrieve the name of the currently logged in user. My login method calls a token manager which builds the token and adds the appropriate claims. See below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] TokenViewModel vm)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.Email);
                var isLoginRequestValid = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, vm.Password);

                if (!isLoginRequestValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Username or password is incorrect");
                }

                return Ok(new TokenViewModel { Token = _tokenManager.BuildJwtToken(vm.Email) });
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex);
            }
        }
```

and token manager:

```
        public string BuildJwtToken(string email)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_config["Jwt:Issuer"],
                _config["Jwt:Audience"],
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(double.Parse(_config["Jwt:ExpireTime"])),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

I've reviewed quite a few posts regarding this issue and still am yet to find a solution. The authentication itself is working fine. Furthermore if I inspect `User.Identity` and exam it's claims at the time of the request, then I am able to see a claim that has the name (which is an email `test@test.com` in this case) in it. See screenshot below which shows the first claim is the email claim and contains a value of `test@test.com` however I'm unable to retrieve the `Claims` directly through `User.Identity`:

[image]

Why is my `User.Identity.Name` still null here despite having successfully added the claim?

Comment: I only see you're filling the emailaddress claim. you should fill the name claim: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830898/usejwtbearerauthentication-does-not-get-user-identity-name-populated/41831919#41831919

Comment: yep didn't see that post- this should be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I needed to add the claim:

`new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email)`

as only using:

`new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, email)`

does not hook up the claim to identity

This addition was in my `BuildJwtToken(string email)` method. Now everything is being hooked up properly. Hope this helps someone else in the future