# I can Authenticate with my JWT but my Name claim is not recognised in my ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I can authenticate to my ASP.NET Core 2.2 web api using a JWT but the `Name` property of the `Identity` is null.

The claim is there, though.

Here's the JWT which is decomposed:

```
{
  "id": "1-A",
  "name": "Pure Krome",
  "email": "<snip>",
  "picture": "https://<snip>",
  "locale": "en-au",
  "permissions": [
    <snip>
  ],
  "iss": "<snip>",
  "sub": "google-oauth2|<snip>",
  "aud": "<snip>",
  "exp": 1597609078,
  "iat": 1496325742
}
```

and here's what the server is seeing:

[image]

also .. it seems to "recognise" my email claim, though? (note: I've just obfuscated the real email value)

[image]

So I thought `name` isn't a recognised claim .. so I tried seeing if there's some standard rules for this and found [IANA has a list of reserved and custom claims](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml). `name` is the first one for custom claims.

Is there some trick I need to do to get ASP.NET Core security to recognise my `name` claim as `NameClaimType` ?

Why does `email` claim get recognised?

Comment: Without reading all the details (not much time right now), I remember an older case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41830898/usejwtbearerauthentication-does-not-get-user-identity-name-populated/41831919#41831919 , does this help?

Comment: You can set NameClaimType on the authentication scheme through its validation settings AFAIK. It's expecting a different claim type now.

Comment: @juunas >It's expecting a different claim type now.  Do you have some extra info to explain what you are suggesting?

Comment: You can set like: `.AddJwtBearer(o => o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" })`. That'll change which claim it uses to populate the name.

Comment: Ok wow - that worked @juunas! Post that as an answer please. Also, why did that work when the "default" settings, doesn't? weird that "email" claim is found, but not name ??

Comment: There's a set of mappings from JWT claims to the MS claims [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L50). As you can see, there's a mapping from `email` but not from `name`, which is why one works but the other doesn't. You'll also see that `unique_name` is what's mapped to that more verbose version of the `name` claim.

Comment: @KirkLarkin oh wow! that's a great find! And... why the hell is this JWT class under an ActiveDirectory repo? oh wow ... there's so many AD specific claims, also :/ Finally, is `unique_name` a common naming convention for this claim? or is `name` the claim used, more commonly? Is this doc'd anywhere? I thought my IANA doc (https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml) was the suggested standard .. which I thought would be the common way for things?

Comment: Also to note @KirkLarkin the link you provided was to `SYSTEM.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` .. which I'm not using. I'm using `MICROSOFT.IdentityModel.Tokens`.

Comment: I don't know why it's `unique_name`, but I've only ever seen `name` used "in the wild". There's a lot of history and legacy around all of this stuff. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/550) might shed some light on it. Although it might be confusing, the source code link I posted is correct if you're using `AddJwtBearer`. You can verify this by following the source code and its chain of dependencies. I can't explain all of that in a comment and you already have a valid answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's expecting a different claim type than what you have.
You can set like:

```
.AddJwtBearer(o => o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = "name"
})
```

That'll change which claim it uses to populate the name.